# Change max memory heap for Java on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, scala

I am trying to change the max memory size "heap" for Java on Mac OS X. I have read many places to change "-XX:MaxPermSize", but I can't find the file and don't know where to change that setting.

Comment: Why do you have the "scala" tag here?  If you're running Scala, the answer is _not exactly the same_ as for Java (if you're using `scala` not `java -cp /.../scala-library.jar:...`).

Comment: What I've done in the past is move ```/bin/java``` to ```/bin/realjava``` and then create a shell script ```/bin/java``` which calls the real one with certain default settings. However, I advise against this. You're much better off tuning each individual JVM to its exact requirements.

Answer (score 13):

you can set the memory available to the java VM using this parameters:

```
-Xms64m -Xmx200m
```

-Xms specifies the minimum memory; -Xmx the maximum one.

You have to specify them when you run your app. For example, if you a jar named app.jar, you can run it typing

```
java -Xms64m -Xmx512m -jar app.jar
```

I think that on a 32 bit machine you can't give the JVM more than 1Gb.

Comment: if you use an IDE, you can probably set these parameters into the project's settings.
In eclipse, for instance, you can do that clicking on Run->Run Configurations

Comment: Why only 1G? Isn't it 3G or 4G in theory?

Comment: With a 32-bit architecture you can have maximun 4GB of physical memory, but the available memory that an application, a process etc. can use depends on many factors.
For instance, the OS needs an amount of memory for itself to handle system processes etc.

I don't know where the VM memory limit comes from, I'm sorry. Anyway, I think it also depends on the OS you are currently using.
Under Windows, I have never been able to give more than 1GB to the VM

Comment: I am talking about 1GB, but actually I don't remeber which was the exact amount

Comment: On OS X Mavericks, the default java installation doesn't support -Xsm64m. We omitted this and everything worked out fine

Answer (score 10):

I was using the WEKA and I got the same problem.
Here, I found the solution, and it was easy.

Go to Application==>
      Left click on specific application (like Weka)==> Show Package Content==> Contents==>Info.Plist==>Java==>
      VMOptions==> increase the size of memory as you want (in my mac the default was 1 Gb, I increased to 6 Gb)

Comment: I prefer this answer because it's straightforward & simple and it provides a permanent fix.

Answer (score 2):

Max heap size is set using `-Xmx` switch.

-XX:MaxPermSize is used to specify the max size of perm generation which is a subset of the total heap

Comment: The -Xmx switch doesn't change the memory size globally, it only works with one class at a time. I am wondering how to change the memory allocation globally for all scripts.

Comment: @user1435853 where did you read that -Xmx is not global? It applies to the entire JVM.

Comment: What file do I edit to I set "-XX:MaxPermSize." The "java -Xmx" command doesn't work for me unless I specify a class. It doesn't globally change the heap memory setting.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "global" setting. The JVM has a default value it uses, which you can override when you invoke it.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to run a java program with an extremely large array in the Terminal. It kept running out of memory but I fixed the problem by increasing memory allowed per thread:

```
$ java -Xss12G name
```

Here the `-Xss12G` tells the java runtime to allocate 12Gb per thread and then run `name`. Similarly `-Xss4G` uses 4Gb per thread. The `$` is the `Terminal` console prompt and will probably have the folder and your name.

Note: If you're not using threads then your allocating the memory to use for your current program or the main thread you're running in.

By writing the command `java -X` in the Terminal you will get more details on allocating heap and thread memory:

```
$ java -X
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're launching the application from Terminal, you'd supply the arguments on the command line:

```
java -XX:MaxPermSize=128m ...
```

This is the same as on any other platform.

If you need to set this for an application bundle (i.e., a Java app that looks like a regular, double clickable Mac app), you'll need to edit the info.plist file, which is located inside the bundle and is not normally visible.

[This page](http://blog.bensmann.com/set-intellij-java-options-on-mac-os-x) has instructions on how to do this for IntelliJ, but is applicable to other bundled Mac Java apps, as well.